# Java ImageView get position and set alignment

Tags: java, html, swing, imageview, jeditorpane

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.html

JEditorPane contains within itself the ImageView.
I can get the size and alignment:

```
    ImageView.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS)); //20px
    ImageView.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS)); //20px
    ImageView.getAlignment(View.X_AXIS)); //0.5
    ImageView.getAlignment(View.Y_AXIS)); //1.0
```

I need to get the coordinates x/y (absolute or relative) and change the y alignment to 0.75. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html 
or simplified version http://java-sl.com/tip_view_rectangle.html

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the value derives from the *align* attribute of the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#img) tag, as defined in the applicable [*HTML 3.2 Reference Specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32). Values other than *left* (0.0), *middle* (0.5) or *right* (1.0) are not supported directly.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I ran into the same problem. The only way to fix this, or so I did it, was, to create your own ImageView and overwrite the vAlign value in its setPropertiesFromAttributes() function. Problem is, that setPropertiesFromAttributes is protected, so you have to copy and paste the whole original code of ImageView into your own, and then replace the code to:

```
    vAlign = 1.0f;
    if (alignment != null) {
        alignment = alignment.toString();
        if ("top".equals(alignment)) {
            vAlign = 0f;
        }
        else if ("middle".equals(alignment)) {
            vAlign = .5f;
        }
    }
    vAlign = .745f;
```

You also need to create your own HTMLEditorKit and overwrite getViewFactory():

```
@Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {

        return new HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory() {

            public View create(Element e) {

                View v = super.create(e);

                Object o = e.getAttributes().getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);

                if (o instanceof HTML.Tag) {

                    HTML.Tag kind = (HTML.Tag) o;

                    if (kind == HTML.Tag.IMG) {
                        return new MyImageView(e);
                    }
                }
...
```